# How to replace & in xml if we have in two places of xml tags

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

I have xml xml like this below

```
<ResiPhone>9702039191</ResiPhone>
<Mobile>09702039191</Mobile>
<OccupationType>S</OccupationType>
<OfficeAddress1>GINGER HOTEL GODREJ & BOYCE COMPLEX GATE</OfficeAddress1>
<OfficeAddress2>8 E EXP HIGHWA & PHIROJISHA NAGAR VIKROLI</OfficeAddress2>
```

It is common to have & symbol in address tags. I am parsing this xml using below code

```
String szInputXMLData=szInputXML.replaceAll( "&([^;]+(?!(?:\\w|;)))", "&amp;$1" );
 inpXMLDoc = DocumentHelper.parseText(szInputXMLData);
```

This replaceAll is working for if we have & character only one time in the xml. If we have multiple times how to replace all the & characters? Please help to solve this problem

Comment: It's not XML. Please don't call it XML, it only confuses people. You have some non-XML which you want to turn into XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay Do you mean if i have & symbol in xml it should not be consider as xml? I have & symbol in flat String and forming xml from the string. While forming , In address i have & symbol in the Address tags. If i try to parse using DocumentHelper i am not able to parse. replaceAll is not working if i have & in multiple places of my tags. Is there anyother way to parse it?

Comment: Absolutely. The fragments you showed are not legal XML. When generating XML, & in text should be output as `&amp;`